# Can I call a Java method from Google App Script?

Tags: java, google-apps-script

What I try to do is to set a bidirectional communication between REST API and Google App Script.

I know that I can send text from App Script to Java (Java calls a function from App Script) that runs locally. But I do not know how to invoke a method in the Java side from App Script.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a REST API to call the method and use [URL Fetch Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/) of app Script to call the API